# How to handle errors in Reactjs Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am a beginner using Apollo. I wanted to know, how error handling is done in Mutations and Queries.
Currently, I have an Error component, which is a modal. The component looks like this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {Modal} from "antd";

const Error = ({ error }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  return (
   <Modal
        title = "خطا به وجود آمده است"
        visible={visible}
        onOk = {() => {
            setVisible(false);
          }
        }
        cancelButtonProps={{ type: "text"}}
        okText="تایید"
        cancelText=" "
        >
       <p>
           متن خطا:
           {error.message}
       </p>
   </Modal>
  )
};


export default (Error);
```

The way I am handling error right now is simply as follows. What should I do if I want the error to not interrupt continuing the code?

```
{error && <Error error = {error}/>}
```